# three variables=1array 1 heap allocated memory& uint64 type variable changing 1 array should reflect the changes in other arry/ How to assign address

Tags: c

So this is my minimal produced code

```
float *validate_c=malloc(sizeof(float)*2);
uint64_t c;
float cl[2];
```

But I could not try to figure out any solution that changing in validate_c should automatically be reflected in cl. I know cl has cl +0 and cl +1 address so I was thinking assigning at these two memory address to the other this can work but I dont want this i can assign validate_c to cl only through `uint64_t c`

something like dividing c to contain address for all validate_c so there should be 1 to 1 index matching is it possible in C, but it sounds wrong, I really dont want this this way. can I do this and what if my validate_c and cl would be huge then what would be the solution

Comment: You want that changes made in validate_cl should reflect in cl ? This is not possible because both arrays have different memories, you would have to manually update the other array. Can you explain *why* you need to do this so we can provide some help ?

Comment: If they are always contain the same values then why do you need two variables? It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. And can you please fix up the post title - it make no grammatical sense.

Comment: @PragunSaini so ioctl I am only getting c and c is like `c=(uint64_t)&cl[0]` in userspace I am getting userspace validate_c by scrolling through userspace memory in ioctl implementation in kernel and getting validate_c now I want 1 to 1 mapping between whats in c which is cl base address to validate_c

Comment: You seem to have attempted to provide a [mre]. Good. But please read up on the details. You were to rigourous on the "minimal" and the "reproducible" is lackking.

Comment: @kaylum its a test that I created to check if it works or not. so idea is can this be done. My real code aint any different that what it does basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a pointer to float and an array of float so that accessing to consecutive floats via the pointer also affects the values in the array.
If you use malloc() for initialising the pointer, you will end up with two separate memory areas, one malloced one in the defined array.
In order to have the desired effect just point the pointer to the defined array.

```
float cl[2];
float *validate_c=cl;
```

This achieves this part of your description

> changing in validate_c should automatically be reflected in cl.

I think this is what you want.

The part about

> dividing c to contain address for all validate_c

I think you are only trying to achive the above. So I consider the proposed solution above to be the answer to your question.

If you want to access the same values via `validate_cl`, `cl` AND `c`.
We could be looking at `union`s. But that is risky and not 100% within standard. I won't go into details if it is not needed.